# C++ compiler optimization for linear pointer comparisons

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I'm having the following code example (fairly representative of actual code), and I'm trying to make the compiler not emit comparisons for the inline index checks in `getVal` (line 32).

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using TValue = uint32_t;

struct CI {
    TValue* func;
};

struct LS {
    TValue* top;
    CI* ci;
};

LS* makeState() {
    auto s = new LS();
    s->ci = new CI();
    s->ci->func = new TValue[4];
    s->top = &s->ci->func[3];
    return s;
}

inline int assertTop(LS* s, int idx) {
    const TValue* o = s->ci->func + idx;

    return ((uintptr_t)o <= (uintptr_t)s->top) ? 1 : 0;
}

inline uint32_t getVal(LS* s, int idx) {
    const TValue* o = s->ci->func + idx;

    if (o >= s->top) {
        return -1;
    }

    return *o;
}

void check(LS* s) {
    if (assertTop(s, 3)) {
        printf("%d %d %d", getVal(s, 0), getVal(s, 1), getVal(s, 2));
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto s = makeState();
    check(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Practically, since this code can't be reached if the comparison in `assertTop` fails, and no other code with side effects is executed in between, these additional checks (emitted in `check`'s usage of `getVal` as can be seen on [the godbolt output](https://godbolt.org/z/BHUKr0)) should not be needed.

I understand that pointer comparison is a 'weird' scenario that compilers usually will take the 'safe' route for and not optimize, but is there any other way to have the compiler *not* emit these checks, without actually removing the check from `getVal`?

Comment: if the checks are not needed why dont you remove them?

Comment: What about `#ifdef SOME_FLAG /* do the check */ #endif`? Then you could manually decide if you want to compile it in or not, e. g. via compiler flags: `-DSOME_FLAG=1`. Maybe want to invert default behaviour? `#ifndef SUPRESS_CHECK`

Comment: I am assuming you are already compiling with maximum optimisations and inlining enabled? This should be just-about doable, given that they are constants and there are no side-effects. Have you tried doing the same code but using distances instead of pointers?

Comment: @user463035818 I assume in the more general case the check protects for buffer overfflow errors, but OP would like to reduce the number of times the check is done in a safe way, but occasionally using the assertTop pre-check?

Comment: If `o == s->top`, `assertTop` returns true but the check in `getVal` takes the return path. (It does not make a difference, however)

Comment: In the 'real' code, the pointers are managed by external code - as can be seen on the godbolt link, optimizations/inlining don't seem to matter when it comes to this check.

Comment: Perhaps one way forward is that AssertTop actually returns a dummy, ideally template, object, which you then pass in as a third argument to getVal. That version of getval could do a static_assert  and skip the check?

Comment: @Botje - perhaps this was an error when transcribing the code, this is simplified from a patch to the Lua VM; however even when fixing that the output doesn't change.